# Are these PSU plugs compatible with such a mainboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I am unsure on how all the plugs fit together.

I already have this PSU:
be quiet! Pure Power 11 400W https://www.bequiet.com/admin/ImageServer.php?ID=0d038a40192@be-quiet.net&.jpg

There are two 4-pin 12V connectors and a 4-pin connector that comes with the 20-pin connector.

The Maxtang ALN-10 mainboard states 12V/19V and seems to have a 4-pin power plug: https://www.maxtangpc.com/industrialmotherboards/223.html

I guess the power-plug from Maxtang is non-ITX standard, as for example the Asrock N100DC-ITX https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/N100DC-ITX/index.asp does not have such a plug.

Can I connect my PSU the Maxtang ALN-10 mainboard? ... I was unable to find any explanation to all this ...

Thank You!

Comment: As JourneymanGeek says your power input for these boards is this thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENxYc.png shown in the photos on both the motherboard pages you linked. You are not going to be able to connect a standard power ATX supply to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well no. Its essentially a laptop board that takes in a 19V DC power input directly, in a 'desktop' mini itx formfactor. Essentially while it would fit into a PC case - its not really a 'proper' PC motherboard, its more similar to a NUC or other mini PC type system with a little more space for peripherals.

Rather than a ATX power supply or its smaller cousins, it'll take some flavour of 12 or 19v barrel jack DC power directly from a switch mode power supply, like that of a laptop.

You can't connect your PSU to the mainboard in question the way a normal motherboard would. You'd also plug in your hard drive power to a 4 pin breakout next to the sata port.

In *theory* depending on your power needs you *could* modify some of your current power supply breakouts to a 12v barrel plug, but that's probably a lot more work than finding a suitable laptop style power supply, and covering up the PSU hole. You might end up with a more efficient setup too.